# Threejs: Texture and zooming out

Tags: three.js

I test threejs and I have this problem:

[Please check this link](http://greg.pixfactory.pro/three-test/)

I do not understand why shapes placed in the background are visible through the foreground shape when zoom in and out. Do you have an idea?

[image: Gif Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with z-fighting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting
An easy fix for your case would be to change your "nearPlane" value from .1 to for example 2.

Comment: While that might help, it wouldn't be a bad idea to rescale everything in his scene. The camera extends to 10.000, box is size 1000. Divide all the positions by 1000.

Comment: Completely agree. Just looked at the start of the code and figured I'd provide a quick fix. In addition it might help to move objects that are so close a bit further from each other.

Comment: Thank you, it works well! I take good note to reduce my dimensions.